# How do I get message as a string varible, Discord.Net

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm trying to maka Discord bot using Discord.Net.
I wanna take message as a string variable and use it.

```
    [Command("GetMesage")]
    public async Task GetMssg()
    {
        await ReplyAsync("Write your message now ");
        //Message from user = string message
        await ReplyAsync(message)
    }
```

Comment: You don't u just take the message as the method parameter? `public async Task GetMssg(string message)`

Comment: But thank you for your reply, I am a beginner and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Nevermind, I had some other problems with my code... Thank you so much for your help. Saved my life

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of executing the command and then asking the user to input a message, they can provide the message at the same time the command is invoked.

```cs
    [Command("GetMesage")]
    public async Task GetMssg([Remainder] string message)
    {
        await ReplyAsync(message)
    }
```

This is invoked like `!GetMessage Some Text here` assuming a prefix of `!`